# How pass a prop in my route from my component to a child component with an 'onClick'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've got a component in my react app with an `idTeam`.

When I click on a `Button`, in a child component with an event `onClick`, I want to pass on my `Details` page with this `idTeam` in my props.

Here are my `Route`s & my `Switch`:

```
{/* ... other components ... */}
    <Menu.Item
      name='details'
      active={activeItem === 'details'}
      onClick={this.handleItemClick}
    >
      <Link to="/details">Détails</Link>
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
</div> 
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
  <Route  path='/equipes' component={Teams} />
  <Route  path='/details/:idTeam' component={Details} />
  <Route component={Page404} />
</Switch>
```

My parent Component:

```
const teamsComponents = this.state.teamsList.map((team)=> (
  <TeamItem 
    key={team.idTeam}
    strTeamBadge={team.strTeamBadge}
    strTeam={team.strTeam}
    strStadium={team.strStadium}
    goToDetails={this.goToDetails(team.idTeam)}
  /> 
))
```

And the function `goToDetails()`:

```
goToDetails = (idTeam) => {
  return <Link to={`/details/${idTeam}`} render={(props) => <Details 
  idTeam={idTeam} {...props} /> } />
}
```

And the Child Component:

```
onReceiveDetails = () => {
  this.props.goToDetails()
  console.log('mes props 2 :' , this.props.params.idTeam);
}

<Button
  icon='group'
  label={{ as: 'a', basic: true, content: 'Détails', 
  color:'black' }}
  labelPosition='right'
  color='black'
  onClick={() => this.onReceiveDetails()}
/>
```

When i'm trying to click on my button i've got "_this.props.goToDetails is not a function"...

Any idea to keep this idTeam on Details Page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "Parent Component" try passing the `goToDetails` prop as `goToDetails={() => this.goToDetails(team.idTeam)}` instead of the way you're currently doing it. This will make sure a function gets passed down to the child component (I assume `TeamItem`).

Your parent component would then look like:

```
const teamsComponents = this.state.teamsList.map((team) => (
  <TeamItem 
    key={team.idTeam}
    strTeamBadge={team.strTeamBadge}
    strTeam={team.strTeam}
    strStadium={team.strStadium}
    // -> change the line below
    goToDetails={() => this.goToDetails(team.idTeam)}
  /> 
))
```

Also, in your `goToDetails` function, you may want to use [`this.props.history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)`.push(<YOUR-PATH>)` like this:

```
goToDetails = (idTeam) => {
  this.props.history.push(`/details/${idTeam}`);
}
```

Comment: thx i've got some props but not this id and  i didn't go to my Details page ? maybe my <Link/> or my <Route /> is not correctly format ?

Comment: @E.D - try the extra bits I just added

Comment: thx It works ;) and  I changed the props "key" to "id" and I receive it well props...

Comment: @E.D You should always have a `key` property when creating a list of components from a `.map` function, so I wouldn't recommend getting rid of the `key` prop in your parent component `this.state.teamsList.map(...)` function

Comment: Yes, I know that, I misspoke, I'm sorry.
I added a props corresponding to my idTeam but I kept the Key ;)

Comment: @E.D aah ok great :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TeamItem 
  key={team.idTeam}
  strTeamBadge={team.strTeamBadge}
  strTeam={team.strTeam}
  strStadium={team.strStadium}
  goToDetails={() => this.goToDetails(team.idTeam)}
 /> 
 ))
```

Your function is invoked when the component renders, try using an arrow function